# PyObjC call objective-c function with parameters (passed by value) in python

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

I'm trying to add my **own** Objective-C framework to a python project using pyobjc. The thing is, when I try and call functions with passed by value parameters (haven't tried by reference) it moans and gives me

```
"AttributeError: No attribute function_with_param".
```

Does anyone know why this error is happening? Bare bones code of what I'm doing in python is below. I'm probably being blind, but I haven't found anything on how to do this anywhere. If anyone can help it'd be awesome! :)

```
import objc

bundle = objc.loadBundle("OBJC", globals(),
    bundle_path=objc.pathForFramework('OSX/OBJC.framework'))

OBJC.function_with_param('a')
OBJC.function_without_param()
```

Ps. Sorry for the formatting in advance. Never done this before..!

Comment: Did you generate [metadata](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/metadata/index.html) for your ObjC code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing an underscore, it works when you do this:

```
OBJC.function_with_param_('a')
```

Found it here:
http://lists.stat.ucla.edu/pipermail/computing/attachments/20050825/f9a98389/attachment.pdf

Comment: If this is true, then that must be a method, not a function.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I should have specified that, oops! Thanks for your answer by the way!